# pandas datareader pulling from 'morningstar' results in 404 (was fine 7/27/2018)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, finance, pandas-datareader

I assume the Morningstar API URL panda's is pulling from is no longer available. Can anyone recommend a replacement?

My code (which worked on 7/27/2018);

`df = web.DataReader(ticker, 'morningstar', start, end)`

Is causing error message:

> File "C:...\site-packages\pandas_datareader\mstar\daily.py", line 130, in _dl_mult_symbols
>       resp.status_code, resp.reason))
>
> Exception: Request Error!: 404 : Not Found

The 404 is coming from lines 91-94 in daily.py;

```
def url(self):
    """API URL"""
    return "http://globalquote.morningstar.com/globalcomponent/" \
           "RealtimeHistoricalStockData.ashx"
```

Comment: Looks like others may be having the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51611123/pandas-datareader-iex-source-stopped-working

Comment: Recommending web-sites is off-topic for stackoverflow

Comment: @JoakimDanielson The OP is not requesting a website recommendation.

Comment: @DYZ, then I must have completely misunderstood the second sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Morningstar's API was discontinued in 7/2018. As such, its reader will be deprecated in the next version of Pandas Datarader (0.7.0). See [this issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/557) for more information.

As the above comment notes, there are various alternative sources to obtain equities data, such as Quandl, AlphaVantage, and IEX. See the Pandas Datareader [documentation](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for details.

Answer (score 0):

try to update your "pandas_datereader"
and then use "stooq" or "iex" instead of "morningstar":

df = web.DataReader("TSLA", 'stooq', start, end) 
df = web.DataReader("TSLA", 'iex', start, end)

hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same issue but now i got an alternative way to get the data using pandas_datareader which works fine. Hope it will help you.

> from pandas_datareader.quandl import QuandlReader
>   
>   
>   data = QuandlReader("WIKI/{}".fromat(ticker), start=START, end=END)
>   
>   df = data.read()

Comment: This is not an answer. Should have been posted as a comment.

Comment: The code throws errors when I run it.  format is misspelled and NameError: name 'ticker' is not defined.